# Having real time output from ssh run with php

Tags: php, jquery, ssh

I'm trying to write what is essentially an interactive ssh system with php, I need to have php execute commands on a remote server with ssh_exec or shell and gather the output from the command in real time.

I've messed about with output buffering and flush() until I'm blue in the face and am about to have the command redirect its output to file and have a separate script that polls the contents of this file with sftp and uses jquery to update an output div on page.

Just before I go down this long winded route, does anyone have a solution that works using a single script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as this working reliably with a single script: You have little control over buffering on the server side - `flush()` might or might not work as expected, depending on wether you use `mod_php`, `CGI`, `FCGI` or whatever, and you have absolutely no control over buffering at the client (IE is notorious here).

Been there, done that, did it with AJAX.

Comment: Sounds like you've trodden the road I'm setting off on. Would you be kind enough to share your code? Happy to share back my final solution as a website!

Comment: Or if not, could you outline what you did to get the results back with ajax? The servers I'm talking to might not be web servers so I can't just output to file and fetch with http, would you say executing regular sftp requests and outputting the results to a div with jquery is the right solution? It seems very heavy to me!

Comment: I'd love to, but I may not - it now belongs to the customer. But it was quite easy: I started the external command (in my case it was a long-running import script) and redirected the output into a file, set a session variable $seek=0. The Ajax waited 500ms, read the file from position $seek to the end, remembered the new position in $seek, and gave back the read text.

Comment: You need no webserver on the target machine, as long as you can read the result file (via SSH) from your webserver runnng the script.

Answer (score 0):

Will something like the following not work?

```
$output = shell_exec($theScript);
file_put_contents($someFile, $output, FILE_APPEND);
```

Or have I got the wrong end of the stick?